# How to get specific value from map in Lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have used map as attribute type in Lightning component. In markup how can i print the value from this map? I need syntax only. I am creating map from js controller of component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have to use a child component to get the values from map using javascript

for example

```
<component>

   <c:ChildComponent mapObject="{!v.YourMap}" mapKey="{v.mapKey}"> 

</component>
```

In child component

```
<component>
    <aura:attribute name="mapObject" type="Map" />
    <aura:attribute name="mapKey" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

   <ui:outputText aura:Id="outputTextId" />

</component>
```

ChildComponent controller

```
{
    doInit : function(component, helper) {
        var mapObject= component.get('v.mapObject');
        var mapKey = component.get('v.mapKey');
        var outputText = component.find("outputTextId");

        outputText.set("v.value",mapObject[mapKey]);

    }
})
```

Comment: By the way i found the perfect match [here](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/generic-and-responsive-table-component-in-salesforce-lightning/) which essentially resolved my query. But your answer is also relevant to question so, i marked as answer.